# Are linux package manager installed libraries statically or dynamically linked?

Tags: linux, cmake, shared-libraries, static-libraries, package-management

If `cryptopp` as an example is installed using `sudo apt install libcrypto++-dev` and then included using `#include <cryptopp/base64.h>`, will this library be statically or dynamically linked?

CMakeLists.txt includes `cryptopp` in `target_link_libraries`.

Comment: StackOverflow is about helping people fix their existing programming code. Please read  https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ,    http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. This ***might*** be more appropriate on http://unix.stackexchange.com . Good luck.

Comment: @shellter Thank you for providing the links. Whilst the question may seem silly to an experienced user, to a new C++ user this is a valid question. A large portion of people do not understand how linux/c++ work together regarding system libraries. In terms of code, I am reading a completed, working project and trying to get my head around it.

Comment: While the *question* is definitely related with programming (and, from my point of view, it is **on-topic** here), the *answer* is programming-unrelated: **Check files installed with a package**. If the package installs `.a` files, then these are *static* libraries, `.so` files are *dynamic* libraries. If the package installs *both* `.a` and `.so` files, and you want to know about *preference*, then reformulate your question.

Comment: Crypto++ recently removed CMake. We could not get things configured properly, and we reached our limit when fighting the tool for simple tasks. Use CMake at your own risk. Also see [Issue 506, Remove CMake from library sources](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/issues/506) and [CMake Removal](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/CMake#CMake_Removal) on the Crypto++ wiki.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> will [a library installed via a package manager] be statically or dynamically linked?

It depends on several factors. First, both libraries must be available. In the case of Crypto++ on Unix and Linux, both static and dynamic libraries are available. On Windows, only a static library is provided.

Second, the linker's configuration matters assuming both libraries are available. On Linux with [`ld`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/), the dynamic library is always used by default. On OS X, a dynamic library is also always used by default. On Windows the linker configuration does not factor into things because options control it.

Third, it depends on linker options. On Windows - and if a dynamic library was available - it would depend on the library you link to. It would be either the static on the import library for a dynamic link library. On Linux with [`ld`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Options.html#Options) you can use `:filename` to link with the static library:

> ***-l namespec***
>
> ***--library=namespec***
>
> Add the archive or object file specified by namespec to the list of
>   files to link. This option may be used any number of times. If
>   namespec is of the form :filename, ld will search the library path for
>   a file called filename, otherwise it will search the library path for
>   a file called libnamespec.a.
>
> On systems which support shared libraries, ld may also search for
>   files other than libnamespec.a. Specifically, on ELF and SunOS
>   systems, ld will search a directory for a library called
>   libnamespec.so before searching for one called libnamespec.a. (By
>   convention, a .so extension indicates a shared library.) Note that
>   this behavior does not apply to :filename, which always specifies a
>   file called filename.
>
> The linker will search an archive only once, at the location where it
>   is specified on the command line. If the archive defines a symbol
>   which was undefined in some object which appeared before the archive
>   on the command line, the linker will include the appropriate file(s)
>   from the archive. However, an undefined symbol in an object appearing
>   later on the command line will not cause the linker to search the
>   archive again.

Finally, behavior is not a simple matter when using CMake. The default behavior will likely be to not add anything. Adding `-lcryptopp` or `-l:cryptopp` to your `LDFLAGS` or `LDLIBS` will have no effect because CMake does not honor customary flags. You will have to add the library to every target manually.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Could you clarify if it Is possible to identify if an executable uses static or dynamically linked libraries after the project has been compiled? Aside from running it on a machine with no dependencies installed. Also, can different libraries be linked differently?